# Laravel Faker Factory Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, factory

I have two factories one for categories and another for products. When I run the factory I want to create x number of products for each category generated. how would I write the code to product this?

the definition for the categories is written as this:

```
return [
            'name' => $this->faker->word,
            'slug' => Str::slug($this->faker->unique()->word, '-'),
        ];
```

and the definition for the product is written as such:

```
return [
                'category_id' => 1, //instead of 1 the category id used i want to be random
                'name' => $this->faker->word,
                'slug' => Str::slug($this->faker->unique()->word, '-'),
                'description' => $this->faker->paragraph,
                'price' => $this->faker->randomFloat(2, 0, 10000),
                'is_visible' => 1,
                'is_featured' => 1
            ];
```

as you can see I hardcoded the `category_id`, I wasnt too sure  how to have it automatically generate and create a product per category that exists. I have the factory for the category written as this, to create 10 items

```
Category::factory()
                ->count(10)
                ->create();
```

I tried this for trial and error thinking it would work but I get an error that `category_id cannot be null` .

```
Product::factory()
                ->has(Category::factory()->count(2))
                ->count(20)
                ->create();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    $factory->define(Product::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'category_id' => factory(Category::class), //instead of 1 the category id used i want to be random
        'name' => $this->faker->word,
        'slug' => Str::slug($this->faker->unique()->word, '-'),
        'description' => $this->faker->paragraph,
        'price' => $this->faker->randomFloat(2, 0, 10000),
        'is_visible' => 1,
        'is_featured' => 1
    ];
});
```

For more info, see the source of this copied quote:

> By setting the attribute to an instance of factory() Laravel will lazily create that model as well and automatically associate it

-- https://www.dwightwatson.com/posts/building-relations-with-laravel-model-factories

Comment: i get undefined $factory do i need to import a class? not sure which one. same with the factory() function it says undefined. im using laravel 8

Comment: In Laravel 8 , You can use Category::factory() instead of factory() helper methods. And In Category Model add a trait, 
use HasFactory;

Answer (score 2):

I am using kind of different syntax, but I think it will work / you can change it

In your `Category.php` model

```
public function products() {
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

In `seeder`

```
factory(App\Category::class, 10)->create()->each(function($c) {
    $c->products()->save(factory(App\Product::class)->make());
}); // each Category will have 1 product
```

[Laravel Database Testing Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database-testing#relationships)

Comment: That code works only up to laravel 7.x

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to pass a `CategoryFactory` to `category_id`.

```php
return [
    'category_id' => Category::factory(),
    // ...
];
```

You can read more about factories here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#defining-relationships-within-factories

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create multiple products per each created category, you can do something like this:

```php
// CategoryProductSeeder
$categories = Category::factory(50)->create();


$categories->each(function ($category) {
    $categories->products()->saveMany(
        Product::factory(10)->make()
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked for me since I'm using laravel 8.

product definition:

```
return [
            'category_id' => Category::factory(),
            'name' => $this->faker->word,
            'slug' => Str::slug($this->faker->unique()->word, '-'),
            'description' => $this->faker->paragraph,
            'price' => $this->faker->randomFloat(2, 0, 1000),
            'is_visible' => 1,
            'is_featured' => 1
        ];
```

seeder:

```
Product::factory()
                ->has(Category::factory())->count(50)
                ->create();
```

created 50 categories and 50 products. 1 category assigned to each product.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

public function definition(): array
{
    return [
        'category_id'=>'1',
        'title'=> $this->faker->text(20),
        'slug'  => function ($attr) {
            return Str::slug($attr['title']);
        },
        'content'=> $this->faker->realText($maxNbChars = 200, $indexSize = 2),
        'is_published'=> $this->faker->boolean()
    ];
}
```